# Can i make voice call from android client to sip js web app

Tags: android, sip, voip

I am implementing voip call from android app to web app.I am using linphone as android client and sipJs demo as web app.It doesn't work when i call from linphone app to demo app.I just want to ask whether is it possible to call from linphone to demo app.
SipJs demo: http://sipjs.com/demo-phone/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It should work. You should try https version of Sipjs [Sipjs](https://sipjs.com/demo-phone/)  or [Jssip](https://tryit.jssip.net)